# Prime Factoring Function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, primes, prime-factoring

I am trying to make a function that will display a number's prime factors with a list (infinite) that I give it. Here is what I have so far:

```
-- Here is a much more efficient (but harder to understand) version of primes.
-- Try "take 100 primes" as an example (or even more if you like)
primes = 2 : primesFrom3 where 
    primesFrom3 = sieve [3,5..] 9 primesFrom3
    sieve (x:xs) b ~ps@(p:q:_)
      | x < b     = x : sieve xs b ps
      | otherwise =     sieve [x | x <- xs, rem x p /= 0] (q^2) (tail ps)



-- Write a function that factors its first argument using the (infinite)
-- list of available factors given in its second argument
-- (using rem x p /= 0 to check divisibility)
primeFactsWith :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
primeFactsWith n (p:ps) = if (rem n p /= 0) then
                                (primeFactsWith n ps)
                          else (primeFactsWith p ps)
```

The top half was not written by me and works just fine. I am trying to get the second half to work, but it isn't. Read the comments in the code to better understand exactly what I am trying to do. Thanks! Oh and please don't just spout the answer. Give me some hints on how to do it and maybe what is wrong.

Comment: You might also try `primes = 2 : 3 : sieve [5,7..] 9 primesFrom3 where ...` and compare the *memory usage* (and times too) for increasing `n`s in `main = print (primes !! n)`. Run it as standalone executable (`$> primes +RTS -s` to see the stats), compiled with optimizations switch -O2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What's wrong

The problem is that you do a recursive call in both branches, therefore the function will never stop.

### Some Hints

To build a recursive list-producing function, you'll need two branches or cases:

- **Base case** no recursive call, this stops the recursion and returns the final part of the result.
- **Recursive case** here you modify the parameters of the function and call it again with the modified parameters, possibly also returning a part of the result.

You need two sub branches at the recursive branch. One if you've found a prime factor, and another if the current number is no prime factor.

Here is a skeleton, you need to fill in the parts in the `<>` brackets.

```
primeFactsWith :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
primeFactsWith n (p:ps) = if <halt condition> then
                            <final result>
                          else if (rem n p /= 0) then
                            <not a factor - recursive call 1>
                          else 
                            <found a factor - return it, 
                             and make recursive call 2>
```

- If you have found a prime factor, you can divide the number by it, to get a smaller number, without that factor. To perform integer division Haskell provides a function named `div`.
- If you reach the number 1, you have generated all prime factors and you can stop. The final part of a prime factors list, that comes after all its factors, is an empty list.
- You can drop any prime from your infinite list if you no longer need it, but be aware that a number could contain a prime several times in the factors list. If you want to drop `p` you can just use `ps`, from the pattern; if you want to keep `p` you must use `(p:ps)`.
- The cons operator `(:)` can be used to build a list. You can use it to return one number of the result list, and use a recursive call to find the remaining numbers, e.g.

  `x : foo y z`

I hope that helps, if you have any questions don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: "p is an Integer but n is an List of Integer". Nope, according to `primeFactsWith :: Integer -> [Integer] -> [Integer]`, in `primeFactsWith n (p:ps)`, `n` is an `Integer`, `p` is an `Integer`, and `ps` is `[Integer]`

Comment: "You try to pass the p as a Parameter to primeFactors where it expects [Integer]". OP does pass `p` as a parameter to `primeFactsWith`, but in the first position. Where it expects an `Integer`, which `p` is.

Comment: I seems I have miss read the function of the OP. The part about the type mismatch, is nonsense I'll remove it. The rest of my answer shouldn't be affected by that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint.

So you're recursing, which is good.

In one branch you keep looking for factors of `n`. In the other branch you seem to look for the factors of `p`, which is a bit weird, but whatevs.

Where do you return the factors of `n` you've found?